# Mirth Connect Filename sent needs original file name and date sent

Tags: filenames, mirth

I have tried a few different things when sending filename.
It seems like it does not like using
$OriginalFilename)$(date.get('yyyy-MM-dd').
It wants to add date after file extention.
Is it possible in Mirth to even do this?
Thank you in advance:)

Comment: $OriginalFilename includes the extension.   You can do a replace in your transformer.  What is the file extension and I will post an example as my answer.

Comment: I need to have my filename to be sent either as ex: Palmer02032022.txt or as Palmer_02032022.txt Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your message transformer. (can be either source or destination side)

```
var newfilename = sourceMap.get('originalFilename').replace('.txt','') + DateUtil.getCurrentDate('yyyy-MM-dd') + '.txt';

channelMap.put('newfilename',newfilename);
```

After that, just put ${newfilename} in for the destination file name.

Comment: Thank you Gavin..I am going to try this and let you know what happens:)

Comment: If it works, please don't forget to accept my answer.